# Residual diagnostic plot of mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am fitting a mixed-effects model with the following specification:

```
mixed_eff_model <- lmer(log(Y) ~ A + B + C + D + (D | M), 
                       data = data_df,
                       REML = FALSE,
                       control = lmerControl(optimizer = "Nelder_Mead"))
```

The output is as follows:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: log(Y) ~ A + B +  C + D + (D | M)
Data: data_df
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "Nelder_Mead")

  AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 392207.9  392298.8 -196095.0  392189.9    178993 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4909 -0.6930 -0.2866  0.3907  8.1989 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name                      Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 M              (Intercept)               2.0710   1.4391       
                 D1                       5.1665   2.2730   0.46
 Residual                                 0.5235   0.7235       
 Number of obs: 179002, groups:  M, 3

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)               -1.807e+02  3.262e+00 -55.413
A                         2.462e-03  8.726e-04   2.822
B                         9.098e-03  5.228e-04  17.402
C                         9.437e-02  1.563e-03  60.371
D1                       -1.065e+00  1.312e+00  -0.812
```

When I plot the residuals using: `plot(mixed_eff_model, type = c('p', 'smooth')`, the output is as follows:

[image: residual_plot]

I have two questions:
1. Does this indicate that the linear model is potentially misspecified?
2. How do I correct the model to account for this observation?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of observations:

- From the output, it seems that you only have three groups for the grouping variable `M`. These are too few to meaningfully estimate the variance of the random effects you have included. Typically more than 10-20 groups are required to get stable estimates of the heterogeneity.
- The shape of the residuals suggests that you have heteroscedasticity with a smaller variance of the residuals for larger fitted values. Moreover, there are also some indications that perhaps your outcome `Y` has a lower bound.
- Some possible solutions are to account for the bounded nature of your outcome in case this is true, and investigate whether the heteroscedasticity is attributed to some of the predictors. The latter could be done using the `lme()` function from package **nlme**, which allows to specify a variance function via its `weights` argument.

Comment: you are absolutely right, `Y` has a lower bound. In fact I am bounding `Y` to focus on the region of practical relevance. Also, my main aim is an estimation of variance associated with the slope against the predictor `D`. Since the three levels of M are only a small sample of levels that M can have, I tried modeling it as a random effect. However, following your first comment, perhaps a mixed-effects model is not the correct specification in this case since I have only three levels of M? Could you suggest an alternative model specification (e.g., beta-regression?)

Comment: If `M` only has three levels you could model it as fixed effect instead. Regarding the bounded nature of your outcome, you could try Beta-regression if you also have an upper bound or a model for semi-continuous data if you only have a lower bound.

Comment: Well, `M` can have multiple levels but then I have observations only on 3 levels (this is why I thought of modeling as a random effect). It appears to me from your valuable observations that a two-stage model for the semi-continuous data is a good option.